# Upper bound for a convex fractional function

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Consider the following convex fractional function

$$f\left( {\bf{x}} \right) = \frac{1}{{a - {{\bf{b}}^T}{\bf{x}}}}$$
where ${a - {{\bf{b}}^T}{\bf{x}}} \ge 0$. Is it possible to obtain a linear or quadratic upper bound function for it?

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? The entire set $\{x: a\geq b^Tx\}$?

Comment: I think it is the positive part of a hyperboloid. Check for Fenchel transformation. [Do not know how much it will be helpful for you.]

Comment: In general, no, it cannot be done. After all, $f(x)\rightarrow +\infty$ as $a-b^Tx\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. Actually, the domain of $f(x)$ is limmitted and never becomes $\infty $. In other words, In my problem, $$ f(x) \to {10^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can just look at the simple example, where you are in dimension 1, and you have $\frac{1}{a-bx}$. I don't quite know what you mean by quadratic upper bound, but as $x$ tends to $a/b$ this tends to infinity. any function bounding it would also have to be ill-defined (infinite) at the point $a/b$.